# Hiding or removing DIV without ID

Tags: javascript

I have website with many `DIV`s. Each contains a single product. I would like to remove or hide those with certain names. 
For example - I would like the script to hide all the `DIV`s containing the name of "food".

As soon as you do this? I was looking for answers in other threads, but I do not have divs with its own ID.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

```
<div 
    data-id="AAA1"
    data-title="CLoth"
    data-bptf-cost="12"
    data-hat-cost="12"
>
<div 
    data-id="AAA2"
    data-title="Food"
    data-bptf-cost="12"
    data-hat-cost="12"
>
<div 
    data-id="AAB3"
    data-title="Money"
    data-bptf-cost="12"
    data-hat-cost="12"
>
```

Comment: You need to show a minimum attempt at writing the code for this to be an acceptable question on stackoverflow.

Comment: `$("div[data-title='Food']").hide()`-type stuff?

Comment: Marc B is that a real way to query to DOM? I didn't know that the data-title type of attributes worked for querying. That's great to know.

Comment: $("div[data-title='Food']").hide()-Works great. Big, big, big thanks. However I am having a problem with the names in which apostrophes occur. For example, in the code it lookes like this : data-title="Other&apos;s Stuff"-Unfortunately - the elements are not being hidden both while using (Other's Stuff) and also (Other&apos;s Stuff). What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can give each div a different or same ID. For example:

```
<div id="food">Some food</div>
<div id="food">Soome other food</div>
<div id="fruits">Some fruits</div>
```

If you now write a script, and call all ID with the name food to hide, the first two will hide and the fruit will stay open.

A very simple example, but with CSS demonstrating what i just wrote above. As you can see i hide all of the ID's named food.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lf9EN/

Comment: It is a bad practice to give more than one DOM element the same id.

Comment: Never thought of that. Well u can still name them differently, and then select more using css as #div1,#div2,...

Answer (score 0):

**First things first give your divs a closing tag!**

Give this a shot.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    setTimeout(function () {
        var divs = document.body.querySelectorAll('div');
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {

            if (divs[i].getAttribute('data-title') && divs[i].getAttribute('data-title') === 'Food') {

                divs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
            };
        };
    }, 100);
</script>
```

**---Html---**

```
<div data-id="AAA1"
     data-title="CLoth"
     data-bptf-cost="12"
     data-hat-cost="12">
</div>
<div data-id="AAA2"
     data-title="Food"
     data-bptf-cost="12"
     data-hat-cost="12">
</div>
<div data-id="AAB3"
     data-title="Money"
     data-bptf-cost="12"
     data-hat-cost="12">
</div>
```